# BLE как отправлять данные >20 бит

Tags: java, android

Собрал проект по [данным исходникам](https://github.com/danasf/hm10-android-arduino/tree/master/Android/BT4LEDTest)  переделал под свои нужды. И возникла необходимость отправлять данные более 20 бит. Я знаю что BLE передает только 20 бит, но вроде можно отправлять больше. Кто может подсказать как?

Comment: Ну покажите тот код, в котором у вас проблемы. Желательно оставить самое минимальное кол-во кода необходимое для понимания в чем у вас вопрос.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я делил данные и отправлял порциями по 20 байт через определенный промежуток времени (50 ms). Плюс, пришлось делать примитивный протокол для сборки/разборки данных.

Comment: Во общем у меня все заработало с добавлением BluetoothGattCharacteristic.WRITE_TYPE_DEFAULT